# How to upload images using NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, multer

I want to upload the product images using Node Js. So I used multer to upload images. I used postman to test whether it is work, but it returns `Please upload a file`. I changed another image then it says `PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large`.

[image: Unable to detect image]

[image: ayloadTooLarge]

**MyCode**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage(
{
    destination: function(req, file, cb)
    {
        cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb)
    {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
    }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) =>
{
    // reject a file
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png')
    {
        cb(null, true);
    }
    else
    {
        cb(null, false);
    }
};

const upload = multer(
{
    storage: storage,
    limits:
    {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 50
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilter
});


router.post("/upload", upload.single('productImage'), (req, res, next) =>
{
    if (!req.file)
      return res.send('Please upload a file')
    var tempPath = req.file.path
      console.log(tempPath);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "testing version",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node server.js",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "api"
  ],
  "author": "tteam",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Do you use `body-parser` ? If so, Increasing the limit as stated in https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/235 will help

Comment: Yeah!, I also used. But it does not finds the file, says `Please upload a file`

Comment: do u wanna save it to db or in a folder?

Comment: Both. The image in a folder, and its name in db

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine i just have to change the `upload.single('productImage')` to `upload.single('image')` and i did not face any error like `Please upload a file`, Here is my pen it just same as yours and works fine.

https://codepen.io/khanChacha/pen/rbJjYj

`Please upload a file` only occur if you don't choose any file or choose wrong file type

I have updated your code and made few changes now its working check it here:

https://github.com/faiz1996khan/uploads

Comment: it doesn't recognize upload file and says, `Please upload a file`

Comment: Are you using this `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form show your html

Comment: check my github repo in my answer, i have updated it now your code is working after making same changes.

Comment: Ok, I used your code but I got error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ttest\Downloads\Compressed\uploads-master\api\routes\uploads\2019-04-18T14:02:45.456Z55460132_25_63992_n (1).jpg'`

Comment: Have you changed something this look like an error due to some incorrect path,make sure that all paths are correct one more thing you should use `express.static` to give static paths or some other module in node

Comment: I did not change anything, only change the `package.json` start app

Comment: where should I use `express.static` ?

Comment: whenever we use express in node.so to serve static files we use `express.static` to config path for staric files

Answer (score 1):

It will become easy to store files after converting in string you just have to convert string in image in your frontend

Convert image in to `base64` string using this code in your api and also don't forgot to delete file from upload folder

```
"img": new Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync(req.file.path)).toString("base64")
```

To delete the file

```
let resultHandler = function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("unlink failed", err);
    } else {
        console.log("file deleted");
    }
}
fs.unlink(req.file.path, resultHandler);
```

At your routes import `multer`:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: __dirname + '/uploads/images' });`
```

Add upload.single('img') in your request:

```
router.post(
    '/fellows-details',
    authorize([Role.ADMIN, Role.USER]), 
    upload.single('img'),
    usersController.fellowsdetails
);
```

If you don't use the `unlink` function it cause error because it first store `buffer` values in folder and than convert it to `base64`.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ttest\Downloads\Compressed\uploads-master\api\routes\uploads\2019-04-18T14:02:45.456Z55460132_25_63992_n (1).jpg'

I think the issue seem to be with location where you store the uploaded file. You need to check for existence of `upload/` before storing the file.

**user.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

let UPLOAD_LOCATION = path.join(__dirname, 'uploads');
fs.mkdirsSync(UPLOAD_LOCATION); //create `uploads/` folder, if it doesn't exists
```

Use this location for storing the upload file

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, UPLOAD_LOCATION);
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  }
});
```

For reference, you can check [how to configure upload path in multer](https://github.com/sridharrajs/nodejs-express-multer-pug-file-upload/blob/master/app.js)